# Multiplication of variables doesn't display

Tags: javascript, html

In the code below, the "result" displayed would be zero as 2 * 0. However, there is a button that adds 2 to "number2". Upon clicking on it, the "result" should be 2 * 2, rather than 2 * 0. My problem is that it ends up showing up as zero.

```js
let number1 = 2;
let number2 = 0;

const add2 = () => {
  number2 += 2;
  display();
};

let result = number1 * number2;

const display = () => {
  document.getElementById("result").innerText = result;
};

display();
```

```html
<p><span id="result"></span></p>

<button onclick="add2();">click me</button>
```

Comment: Well you do not rerun the multiplication..... `let result = number1 * number2;` does not magically run, it is once and done....

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the result variable globally and then make sure you calculate it each time you click the button. Below I've created a function called calculate to do this:

```html
<html>

<body>
    <p><span id="result"></span></p>

    <button onclick="add2();">click me</button>
   <script>


    let number1 = 2;
    let number2 = 0;
    let result;

    const add2 = () => {
        number2 += 2;
        result = calculate();
        display();
    };
    
    const calculate = () => {
      return number1 * number2;
    };

    const display = () => {
        document.getElementById("result").innerText = result;
    };
    result = calculate();
    display();

   </script> 

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the `result` variable **globally** which always **holds** the result.

```js
    let number1 = 2;
let number2 = 0;
let result;
const add2 = () => {
        number2 += 2;
        result = number1 * number2;
        display();
};

result = number1 * number2;
const display = () => {
      document.getElementById("result").innerText = result;
};

display();
```

```html
 <p><span id="result"></span></p>
 <button onclick="add2();">click me</button>
```